# WHY THE FUNCTION IS RETURNING NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I try to run the function below, the line of code is returning `Nan`, when it's supposed to return a number.

```js
 var next = list[last]+list[before];
```

This is the full code:

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var list = [0, 1];
  if (n === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return [0]
  } else {
    while (n > 1) {
      var last = list.length;
      var before = last - 1;
      var next = list[last] + list[before];
      list.push(next);
      n -= 1;
      return list;
    }
  }
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(8));
```

Comment: if `last = list.length`, then `list[last]` will be `NaN`. Maybe you mean `last = list.length-1`?

Comment: To expand on @kmoser's comment, any array access for `array[array.length]` will be undefined because array indices start at `0`

Comment: Typically, something named _"fibonacci generator"_ would return a sequence of more than three numbers. You probably want to move the `return` statement out of the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to access `list[last]`, which is `list[list.length]`. However, because a list of length `1` has a single item at index `0`, you're getting `undefined`. So, use `list.length - 1`:

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var list = [0, 1];
  if (n === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return [0]
  } else {
    while (n > 1) {
      var last = list.length - 1;
      var before = last - 1;
      var next = list[last] + list[before];
      list.push(next);
      n -= 1;
      return list;
    }
  }
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(8));
```

(Also, your function has a small issue - `return list` runs as soon as the first loop iteration has completed. Move it outside of the loop:

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var list = [0, 1];
  if (n === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return [0]
  } else {
    while (n > 1) {
      var last = list.length - 1;
      var before = last - 1;
      var next = list[last] + list[before];
      list.push(next);
      n -= 1;
    }
    return list;
  }
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(8));
```

Basically, the way it works in JavaScript is that `array[array.length]` will **always** be undefined. It starts at index `0` - so `array.length` is always *one more* than the index of the last element:

```
let nextElementIndex = array.length; // The next element to be added to the array will have the index of nextElementIndex, or array.length AT THIS CURRENT MOMENT
array.push(1); // `1` has the index nextElementIndex
nextElementIndex == array.length; // False, because there's a new element in the array, so the array's length has updated to nextElementIndex + 1.
```

Comment: Move that `return list` line down by one line and this might even resemble a Fibonacci generator 

Comment: Shocker @Phil - I just did a basic replacement of the issue, not the issue with their algorithm - fixing that now!

Comment: @Phil thanks :) is that paragraph with "basically..." inherently correct or flawed? Seems correct to my untrained brain, but hopefully Mr. 6 digits can help :P

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `last = 2`, which makes `list[last] = list[2]` while it only has 2 elements that is `list[0] and list[1]`. Therefore, you get `undefined` out of this one, and when `undefined + list[before]`, it gets `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You just using index out of array range, an `array` has index range from `0` to `length - 1`, so `array[length] + ...` will return `NaN`

But, Something i can change in your code:

1. Try to think about calculating `fibo(n)` from `fibo(n-1)`, not just recalculate from beginning.

Something like this look better:

```
var fibo = function(n){
  // some funky code to check fatal input
  ....

  // init special values
  if(n==0) return []; 
  if(n==1) return [1]; 
  if(n==2) return [1, 1];

  // get previous state 
  var arr = fibo(n-1); 
  var len = arr.length; 
  arr.push(arr[len-2] + arr[len-1]); 
  return arr;
}
```

2. You will hear your computer sound like a helicopter if you must use this function many times. So if you need re-use this, you need something for caching calculated values. Ex:

```
epic_history = {
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 2,
  4: 3,
  5: 5,
  .....
}
```